# Pandas: Censoring subjects in longitudinal data based on criteria in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` of longitudinal data for subjects in a study. Each subject has repeated observations at a different time point `Wave`. One data point `condition_A` is expressed as a string with possible values `(normal, MCI, dementia)` where all subjects have `condition_A = normal` at Wave 1. Some subjects go on to develop `condition_A = dementia` or `condition_A = MCI` at varying time points. Other subjects `condition_A = normal` at all time points.

I am trying to find a way to exclude data from subjects with `condition_A = dementia` from the time point where `condition_A` first equals `dementia` and any future waves, while preserving any preceding data.

Data frame is set up as below:

```
>>> index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4],[1,2,3]*4], names = ('SubjectID', 'Wave'))
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"condition_A":['normal', 'normal', 'normal', 'normal', 'normal', 'dementia', 'normal', 'MCI', 'dementia', 'normal', 'dementia', 'dementia']}, index=index)

>>> df
               condition_A
SubjectID Wave
1         1         normal
          2         normal
          3         normal
2         1         normal
          2         normal
          3       dementia
3         1         normal
          2            MCI
          3       dementia
4         1         normal
          2       dementia
          3       dementia
```

The desired output I want is:

```
               condition_A
SubjectID Wave
1         1         normal
          2         normal
          3         normal
2         1         normal
          2         normal
3         1         normal
          2            MCI
4         1         normal
```

One approach I tried was to use an external `Series` object to store the inclusion/exclusion status of each subject, then use `apply` on each row:

```
>>> df['condition_A_exclude'] = False
>>> subject_list = pd.Series(False, index=index.levels[0])
Int64Index([1, 2, 3], dtype='int64', name='SubjectID')
>>> def determine_condition_A(row):
...     index = row['SubjectID']
...     if subject_list.loc[index]:
...         row['condition_A_exclude'] = True
...     elif row['condition_A']=='dementia':
...          subject_list.loc[index] = True
...          row['condition_A_exclude'] = True
...     return row

>>> df.apply(determine_condition_A, axis = 'columns')
```

This approach works, but it relies on an external Series. I wondered if there was a way to accomplish this in place?

Comment: can you maybe update your example to show a case where a `False` follows a `True` in a group?

Comment: Yes, that was my intention. Just updated the case.

Comment: so you want to drop the whole group in this case? or just the data after it?

Comment: The data after it.

Comment: then [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71035244/16343464) should work for you (and your example output is slightly incorrect) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exclude all data (True or False), per SubjectID as soon as there is a True, you can use [`groupby`+`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummax.html) to compute a mask:

```
mask = df.groupby(level='SubjectID')['condition_A'].cummax()
# updated example with "dementia"
mask = df['condition_A'].eq('dementia').groupby(level='SubjectID').cummax()

df.loc[~mask]
```

output:

```
                condition_A
SubjectID Wave             
1         1           False
2         1           False
          2           False
3         1           False
          2           False
          3           False
```

Comment: Thank you! This does work well. It works by nature of the fact that max(True, False) = True. What about a case where the condition column contains a string? or three different integers (1,2,3) where 2 is the exclusion criteria?

Comment: @ekom12 you can always convert to a boolean (string -> regex or equality ; (1,2,3) -> test on second element or any etc.). Please provide an specific use-case if you want an example ;)

Comment: Yes this works, but you have to put ['condition_A'] after groupby(level='SubjectID'). Thanks!